# Difficulties with showing android calendar in different versions

Tags: calendar, android-calendar

I am trying to open the user's calendar.
I wrote the following code:

```
startMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar").buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(builder.build());

startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that it works in version 4.0 but not in 2.2, which is my target version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At the LogCat, What error are you getting?

Comment: absolutely nothing, that's why I'm stuck...

Comment: that's odd. Can you elaborate a little (probably in the question itself): Are you using Eclipse? Are you deploying to the AVD or the actual device? What is the minsdk/targetsdk values in your app manifest?

Comment: I am using eclipse, 2 different AVD and the tagets are 8/8

Comment: I just copied your code into one of my classes and the activity started and I could see the calender. My target is 2.2 (api v.8). So, what exactly happens when this part of the code is triggered? Does the app crash? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: The app just crashes.

Comment: Does it open the calendar on a new avd 2.2? It doesn't have a calendar default app, so you probably added one somehow, am I correct?

Comment: Well, I run it on AVD with 4.2, but my manifest minsdk/targetsdk are both 8 (2.2). So, if some libraries are not present in 2.2, it shouldn't run.

Comment: It works now, after installing a different calendar on the AVD. Thanx

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget, you can post your solution as the answer and get a badge for it, too!

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things, I installed a different calendar on the AVD and it workes now.